# How to change registered username for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200635/how-to-change-registration-company-name-for-visual-studio-2008/200791) post and followed instructions.

The registry location of HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\\Registration has a Username property but when I change it and open VS it still says something else.

Answer (score 1):

Delete vs000223.dat from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0. It's splash image for Visual Studio 2008. Now if you run Visual Studio 2008, you will see a strange splash 'Visual Studio code name 'Orcas'.
Run 'devenv /setup' from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ (or C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ on Windows x64).
Open Visual Studio 2008, now you should see new registration info.