# How is AssemblyInfo.cs populated?

Tags: visual-studio

When I create a new Visual Studio project, the AssemblyInfo.cs file is pre populated with some default information.

Two lines in particular concern me:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Vagrant Inc.")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © Vagrant Inc. 2014")]
```

Where is Visual Studio pulling the Vagrant information from? (I don't work for Vagrant)

Comment: The project template inserts the name of the user/company that owns the Visual Studio license, as entered when it was first installed.  Sounds like you are using an invalid license :)

Comment: That's concerning. Is there any way to change this or is it tied tightly to the license?

Answer (score 0):

When you installed VS you must have provided some information about the company registered/licensed to used that copy of VS. That's where that information is getting pulled from. You don't need to be concerned about it since you can easily change this. This file only gets populated upon creating a new project, you can change the default values at any time

#### Edit based on comment

Since you are now asking a complete different question that has already been answered here I will simply  attached the links as to **How to change the default values**

[Setting the default values of AssemblyInfo.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7468385/setting-the-default-values-of-assemblyinfo-cs)

[How to change registration company name for Visual Studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200635/how-to-change-registration-company-name-for-visual-studio-2008)

[Changing Visual Studio Registration Information](http://devblog.stuartthompson.net/2010/03/changing-visual-studio-registration-information/)

Comment: Great! how do I change the default values?

Comment: @Ev. now, that's a whole different question that has been already answered here...see my updated answer